# Hidden-class implementation of prototype-based language

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

As [this post](http://thibaultlaurens.github.io/javascript/2013/04/29/how-the-v8-engine-works/) mentions, v8 features a hidden-class implementation while the JavaScript language is prototype- rather than class-based.

Does this mean, in general, a class-based design fits the underlying system better and a prototype-based design only makes the programmer's task easier but not machine-friendly?

Comment: Not "in general", but yes, on our current machines everything is about pointers and structures with offsets, which doesn't fit property names or inheritance well. But notice that "hidden classes" look still very different on the machine level from what you think "class-based" is.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the implementation of prototype-based languages. Could you please have a few more words on the difference between the hidden class and the traditional class in runtime environments?

Comment: The traditional class is all about the static member layout, which is necessary for compilation and execution. In a language with dynamic objects, we need to introduce a layer of indirection to make it executable.