# In terms of a JavaScript engine, are there benefits to implementing prototypal delegation rather than class-based inheritance?

Tags: javascript

Looking at modern JavaScript with classes, my understanding is that this is all syntactic sugar overlying the same prototype-based object model that is used prior to ECMAScript2015. I like working directly with prototype chains, but classes are definitely easier.

So it seems to me that, in JavaScript, programs are likely to all be specified according to a class-based syntax, but are likely to be executed according to the rules of prototype-objects. So there will always need to be some kind of conversion between how JavaScript is written, and how it is executed.

Regardless of how JavaScript is implemented via browsers and other engines, my question is:

**From the perspective of writing a JavaScript engine, are there performance or other benefits in implementing an object-orientated language in terms of prototypal delegation rather than classes?**

==== EDIT

A similar question ([Hidden-class implementation of prototype-based language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954092/hidden-class-implementation-of-prototype-based-language)) has comments that suggest classes in the traditional sense are easier to implement at the compiler level because they can be laid out statically in memory (I think that is implied anyway), but that doesn't allow for dynamic structures such as JavaScript allows for. So it seems to me that it might be possible that prototypal delegation may be a good fit for implementing dynamic objects at the compiler level?

Comment: "_From the perspective of ... implementing an object-orientated language_" ... Shouldn't this be tagged with the language you're creating the implementation ..?

Comment: The benefit of a prototype inheritance model is mostly flexibility - it works really well with the duck typing approach.

Comment: *"some kind of conversion between how JavaScript is written, and how it is executed"* – the disconnect is probably not as big as you imagine. It all gets translated into entirely different data structures behind the scenes anyway. The compiler can do that translation more or less inline while parsing the syntax. It's really mostly just shorthand, nothing more.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what answer you expect. It is harder to write a engine for a flexible language like JavaScript to have a similar performance compared to a static language like c or c++, because optimizations have to be done mostly at runtime (like dead code removal, inlining, ...). The advantage is for the user of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is, in a way, compiled before execution. That's the "conversion" between how the language is written and how it's executed. Furthermore, as you said, many features of newer ES specs are in fact syntactic sugar.

Regardless of the way you declare the classes, they will eventually compile to a similar abstract syntax tree (correct me if I'm wrong). It could either be via an intermediate compiler like Babel, or directly by the executing implementation.

From that perspective, the main drawback of using the more abstract class definitions, from the perspective of writing a JavaScript engine, is that it needs to support a broader syntax.

The way to go, probably, is by reducing the class syntax to the more native prototypal syntax (intermediate compilation) - that's how I would consider implementing it. That *would* lead to a minor performance hit in the compilation phase.

Comment: "*JavaScript is compiled before execution - that is an integral property of the language*" - uh, JavaScript is interpreted? I even remember a particular implementation which had nothing but a parser and an interpreter operating on the AST, for minimal memory footprint.

Comment: Personally I think that JS falls into the gray area. I think it's fair to call the transformations that JS code undergo "compilation" (with lexical scoping and hoisting), but I also see how that can spark confusion. It is not compiled language in the way e.g. C is (one could argue that C can be interpreted as well - anything that can be understood by a human can), but not really interpreted language the way e.g. BASIC is. I will edit.

Comment: @Bergi FWIW later versions of V8 (Chrome's JS Engine) immediately create bytecode out of your sources upon script load. Then this bytecode is interpreted in the JVM, and when optimizations are possible, relevant parts are compiled into native code (for the lifetime of the context).
But this is irrelevant to the question - I think the point is that JavaScript doesn't even have a classical understanding of OOP/inheritance - it is prototype based. Syntax or for that matter, how the things are compiled and optimized, do not matter. You still must support prototypes.

Answer (score 2):

Another perspective is the object composition.

Consider this:

```
class X { method() {} }
class Y extends X { method2() {} }

const y = new Y();
```

Now, in "classical" OOP, `y` would be an object, and it would have two methods, `method` and `method2`.

In prototypical (classic JavaScript) sense, `y` is an object. The object has nothing by itself, but on its prototype, it has a `method2`. Where is the first `method`? Well, if you dig down the prototype's constructor, you'll see that it, also, has a prototype, with `method` a part of it.

Copy-paste from Node REPL:

```
> class X { method() {} }
undefined
> class Y extends X { method2() {} }
undefined
> const y = new Y();
undefined
> y
Y {}
> y.prototype
undefined
> y.__proto__
Y {}
> y.__proto__.constructor
[Function: Y]
> y.__proto__.constructor.__proto__
[Function: X]
```

You need to be able to support people who monkey-patch prototypes of things:

```
> X.prototype.method = () => console.log('I am here now!');
[Function]
> y.method();
I am here now!
```